# Glossary with entries without reference

Tags: glossaries

Is there a command so that the glossary will also display elements without links (an equivalent of `\nocite` in BibTeX)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Quoting p. 47 of the `glossaries` documentation:

> It is possible to add a line in the
>   glossary file without generating any
>   text at that point in the document
>   using:
>
> ```
> \glsadd[<options>]{<label>}
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> To add all entries that have been
>   defined, use:
>
> ```
> \glsaddall[<options>]
> ```