# Acronyms and Glossaries package will not work with RevTex 4.2

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, revtex

I am [following the guide from Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries) on how to use the **glossaries package**. I am trying to work it with **RevTex 4.2**. Below is my sample script:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,
]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{Why Acronyms swill not work? } 
\maketitle

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The output of this file is only the title with no compilation errors. No glossaries or acronyms appearing. I also tried the acronyms package and again without any compilation errors I get blank output.

**What is the solution?**

Comment: You don't actually use any `\gls` commands, if I add `\gls{gcd}` and run `makeglossaries` I get the GCD acronym appearing in the list of acronyms.  Does that work for you? Are you actually [running `makeglossaries`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46732/106162), or maybe looking for [`\glsadd` or `\glsaddall`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14904)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on
[this thread:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562799/is-revtex-documentclass-compatible-with-glossaries-package)
[Is revtex documentclass compatible with glossaries package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562799/is-revtex-documentclass-compatible-with-glossaries-package)
The problem has something to do with the "reprint" option in the revtex documentclass

> \documentclass[
> **reprint**,amsmath,amssymb,aps,
> ]{revtex4-2}

I manged to work around this issue by setting the option to "preprint". After running tex and the creation of the glossary files the option can be set to "reprint" again and tex runs without a problem.

Cheers, 
Carsten

Comment: This actually worked for me as well, setting it to preprint and then back to reprint...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP's issue on this question is just the use of glossaries itself.  The issue in [Is revtex documentclass compatible with glossaries package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562799/106162) is due to `twocolumn` (`reprint` applies this) causing an aux file to be created without some of the directives needed to create the glossary. For that question this should work but will need to be done every time you're updating the glossary files.